# What is causing conda build to report an unsatisfiable specification with my own package?

Tags: build, dependencies, conda, pypi, miniconda

When attempting to conda build a package I'm working on, I get the following error message:

```
conda.exceptions.UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - segtools==1.2.1=py35r341h39e3cac_0
```

I cannot interpret the specifications and what exactly is in conflict. `segtools` refers to my conda package name, `1.2.1` refers to both the conda package version and the version on PyPI. I cannot interpret the `py35r341h39e3cac_0` portion and it only has a singular '='.

I verified `pip install segtools` works in an empty Python 3.5 conda environment just in case it was pointing out some other conflict I was unaware of.

As requested here is a link to my [current meta.yml](https://github.com/EricR86/bioconda-recipes/blob/segtools-1.2/recipes/segtools/meta.yaml).

Comment: Can you please include your entire `meta.yaml` file?

Comment: It is a little lengthy to post straight here but I can [provide a link](https://github.com/EricR86/bioconda-recipes/blob/segtools-1.2/recipes/segtools/meta.yaml)

Comment: What OS are you using? On macOS, gmtk can't be found in the default channels or conda-forge. What version of conda and conda-build are you using?

Comment: "gmtk" is probably erroneously placed in the bioconda channel (since it's not biological science specific). As a sanity check I've upgraded and now conda version is 4.5.5 and my conda-build version is 3.10.5. I can no longer reproduce the issue locally and I'm left with the error message still being reported by the [build machine](https://circleci.com/gh/bioconda/bioconda-recipes/16647?utm_campaign=vcs-integration-link&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=github-build-link)

Comment: Just a heads up I discovered the issue. I removed the "preserve_egg_dir: True" line from my meta.yaml file which seemed to do the trick. I do not understand why.